# perform atomic aggregate read and update in mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have some documents with below format

```
{
    "count_used" : Int64,
    "last_used"  : Date,
    "enabled"    : Boolean,
    "data"       : String
}
```

I use the `last_used` field to sort on within an `aggregate` query so the last used document is served first. I use `updateOne` after the aggregate to bump the last used field using the below query. So every read request will change the last_used field date stamp.

```
updateOne(
    { _id: result['_id']}, 
    {
        $currentDate: { 'last_used': true }, 
        $inc: { 'count_used': 1 }
    }
)
```

The problem i have is clients will make 5 concurrent requests and instead of receiving document 1,2,3,4,5 they will get 1,1,1,2,2 for example.

I'm guessing this is because there is no lock between the read and the update, so several reads get same results before the update is performed.

Is there any way around this?

**Update** with below aggregate nodejs code

```
db.collection('testing').aggregate([{
    $project: {
    last_used  : 1,
    count_used : 1,
    doc_type   : 1,
    _id        : 1,
    data       : 1,
    is_type    : { $setIsSubset: [ [type], '$doc_type' ] }
    }
},
{ $match: {
    $or: query} 
},
{ $sort: { 
    is_type: -1, 
    last_used: 1 
    } 
},
{ 
  $limit: 1 
} ]).next(function (error, result) {  

    db.collection('adverts').updateOne({_id: result['_id']}, {$currentDate: {'last_used': true}, $inc: {'count_used': 1}})        

}
```

The problem is that multiple read requests come in from same client who issues multiple concurrent requests, which means they hit db at the same time and read the same data before the `updateOne` fires.

Comment: Can you add your aggregation query? I wonder what that looks like.

Comment: have you found a way to solve this? I am having a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921005/mongodb-use-findandmodify-on-specific-document-among-multiple-match

Comment: An idea would be to use $merge as the last stage of your aggregation pipeline to avoid having 2 separate queries, but i'm not sure it that would be atomic: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/