# Mongodb use findAndModify on specific document among multiple match

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have documents that look like below

```
let object = [
    {
        id: 4,
        parents:
            [
                1, 2,
            ],
        children: 2
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        parents:
            [
                1, 2,
            ],
        children: 1
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        parents:
            [
                1, 2, 4
            ],
        children: 0
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        parents:
            [
                1, 2, 4
            ],
        children: 0
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        parents:
            [
                1,2,5
            ],
        children:0
    }
]
```

I would like to use `findAndModify` in order to update the children value. It has to be `findAndModify` because I will be working in an multithreaded environment so selection and update must happen in single transaction.

The conditions that I am looking for is when '2' is included in the `parents` array and `children` value is less than 2 where the `children` value is highest and parents count is lowest among the sufficing documents. Then I would like to increment the value of children of the first matching document.

The query that I have come up with right now is below

```
let query =
    {
        parents:
            {
                $elemMatch:2
            },
        children:
            {
                $lt: 2
            }
    };
```

which suffices first few conditionals but unfortunately I don't know how I can select out

```
{
    id: 5,
    parents:
        [
            1, 2,
        ],
    children: 1
},
```

out of

```
{
    id: 8,
    parents:
        [
            1, 2, 4
        ],
    children: 0
},
{
    id: 9,
    parents:
        [
            1, 2, 4
        ],
    children: 0
},
{
    id: 10,
    parents:
        [
            1,2,5
        ],
    children:0
}
```

which is what is currently selected with my query. Again, it has to be a single transaction so writing out another set of query is not possible.

As to why it has to be single transaction, refer to this post [How to limit maximum reference of the parental node in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876787/how-to-limit-maximum-reference-of-the-parental-node-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
query.findAndModify({
    query: { $and: [ { children :{$lt : 2 }}, { parents: { $size: 2 } } ] },
    update: { according to you }
});
```